# Help for Downloadable Product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, downloadable

I am using the fixed calculation for some customer groups.

Everything works in case of simple product but which is not same for Downloadable product.

It looks search page is working fine. But in product detail page, I am facing some issues. So I just want to know :

- Where the downloadable product `getprice()` calculation is being done?

It would be great if you can show me the file (and file-path) which is respondible for downloadable product price calculation logic.
[image: Homepage]

[image: Product Page]

Comment: From admin panel you can enable path hint from System->Configurations->Advancedì->Developer

Comment: Nothing in that like u said.

Comment: It's in System>Configuration>Developer (under Advanced down the bottom)>Debug>Template Path Hints - but you need to be down at your store level not Default. You can also turn on Add Block Names to Hints - and under Developer Client Restrictions, if needed you can add your IP so it doesn't show on live environments.

Comment: @JohnS Please see [here](http://insync.co.in/how-to-enable-template-path-and-block-name-hints-in-magento-commerce/)

Comment: Same File phtml . for homepage and detailpage. but price value php output are different. please help me that way,.